# Spam entries in mail log, but doesn't appear to be from a PHP script?

Tags: php, email, clamav

I'm new to linux, and it appears that my server was blacklisted in the CBL. It looks like one of my Wordpress installations was compromised, and some Malware was installed.

I ran ClamAV, and it found these Malicious files in the outdated Wordpress installation.

I have removed the entire installation from the server, when I run ClamAV again it does not find anything suspicious or infected in the system.

Also, I have added the following to my php.ini file to find spam sending PHP scripts on my server:

```
    mail.add_x_header = On
    mail.log = /var/log/phpmail.log
```

I am still seeing spam entries in my mail.log file, but nothing is showing at all in /var/log/phpmail.log? This file is completely empty.

Here are some examples of the entries I'm seeing in mail.log:

```
Mar 28 19:31:23 localhost sm-mta[23577]: t2Q7MUvi008463: to=<christian.creusot@free.fr>, delay=2+12:08:53, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=16680851, relay=mx2.free.fr. [212.27.42.58], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: 451 too many errors from your ip (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx), please visit http://postmaster.free.fr/
Mar 28 19:31:26 localhost sm-mta[25413]: t2R8l6nK026010: to=<pedraza@verison.net>, delay=1+10:44:20, xdelay=00:02:06, mailer=esmtp, pri=10740867, relay=verison.net. [72.52.10.14], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with verison.net.
Mar 28 19:31:30 localhost sm-mta[7658]: t2Q71Y5L002621: to=<dylanetmazina@gmail.co>, delay=2+12:29:56, xdelay=00:03:09, mailer=esmtp, pri=16140966, relay=gmail.co. [74.125.228.214], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with gmail.co.
Mar 28 19:31:31 localhost sm-mta[17713]: t2RFxunZ004247: to=<chocolatemilkisbetterthansoda@yahoo.co>, delay=1+03:31:35, xdelay=00:08:25, mailer=esmtp, pri=7680920, relay=yahoo.co. [98.137.236.150], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with yahoo.co.
```

I can't seem to figure out what could be causing the spam entries in the mail log.

Any ideas as to what else I can do?

EDIT: also have confirmed that I am not running an open relay in sendmail

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the malware ClamAV found is covering its tracks in some way.

You can see it's sending spam and you've isolated it to at least a Wordpress exploit, so disable the Wordpress installation(s) in question by re-naming the docroot directory. Then re-install WP manually to the latest version.

Always best to run a rootkit check after that if you can too.